# upload a python package to a private pypiserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-wheel, twine

So I've built my Python package using:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Tried to use twine in order to upload the package to my local pypiserver.

`twine upload dist/* --repository-url <MY_REPO>`

Now it asks for username and password but I don't remember I set-upped credentials to my pypiserver (installed using Docker)

Answer (score 1):

The `pypiserver` project is configured with a `-P, --passwords PASSWORD_FILE` flag which sets an Apache htpasswd file for authorization.